# How to export a single Firefox extension as an installable xpi file?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Once upon a time I have installed an extension, that is no longer available: YouTube Smart Pause [image].

Is there any way to *export* this extension back into the *xpi* file, so I can give it to my friends?

There are solutions that allow exporting whole extension collection (FEBE, Firefox sync, etc.). I am asking for a way to export a *single* extension.

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have?

Comment: @mk117 The only current version - only one is maintained. At the moment it is 31.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often you can do the export manually by copying the xpi file out of your firefox profile. This is a Linux example, but a similar method would work for Windows:

```
mkdir somextension
cd somextension/
cp ~/.mozilla/firefox/5x0w1g3w.weave24a/extensions/jid0-k75TfRGfOXPHfEZmJ9cKu5eCgLc\@jetpack.xpi .
mkdir orig
cd orig
unzip ../jid0-k75TfRGfOXPHfEZmJ9cKu5eCgLc\@jetpack.xpi
```

The above example copies an xpi out of my firefox profile into a working directory and then uses unzip to extract the files into a subdirectory orig/

You don't need the extract step if you are simply interested in the xpi file.

Comment: Both answers are correct and dead simple. I sympathize with folks running Linux, and this is the only reason why I accepted this one over the other answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [::Momzillazine::](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions) - Installing Extensions

Extension files are located in the "extensions" subfolder of the ::[profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder):: (single-user) and in the "extensions" subfolder of the ::[installation directory](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installation_directory):: (global); there is one folder per extension, named using their ID codes. To tell which is which, look inside each folder’s "chrome" subfolder where you will find some human-readable information regarding the extension.

**Note**: Starting in Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 / Thunderbird 3.3 / SeaMonkey 2.1), **XPI files are no longer unpacked** when extensions are installed. Instead, the XPI itself is placed in the extensions directory, and files are loaded directly out of the package.

On Windows 7, open folder: "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\"
Go to Mozilla > Firefox > Profiles > *.default > extensions

Here you'll find some xpi files, and your firefox extension .xpi will be among that list.